# Content from async XML source doesn't get updated correctly in vue component

Tags: vue.js

Im struggeling with reactivity in vue and need some help.

My component should show content from a XML document. When switching between different XML documents, some components keep their old value and don't reflect the new content. This seems to happen for XML elements, that have the same id. However I use a unique :key attribute in the v-for loop consisting of the XML documents id and the XML elements id.

This only happens, if I set the content using a data property.

```
<span v-html="value"></span>
...
data() {
  return {
    value: this.xmlNode.firstChild.nodeValue
  };
}
```

When I set the content directly it works as expected.

```
<span v-html="xmlNode.firstChild.nodeValue"></span>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="course">
  <button @click="toggle">Change content</button>
  <edit-element
    v-for="node in courseElementContent"
    :xml-node="node"
    :key="id + '#' + node.getAttribute('idref')"></edit-element>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
Vue.component('edit-element', {
  template: '<div><span v-html="value"></span></div>',
  props: ["xmlNode"],
  data() {
    return {
      value: this.xmlNode.firstChild.nodeValue
    };
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#course",
  name: "CourseElement",
  data: {
      id: 1,
      courseElementContent: null
  },
  created() {
    this.load();
  },

  methods: {
    toggle() {
      if (this.id == 1) this.id = 2;
      else this.id = 1;
      this.load();
    },
    load() {
      var me = this;
      axios.get("content/" + this.id + ".xml").then(
        response => {
          var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(response.data, "text/xml"));
          // get all <content> elements
          me.courseElementContent = doc.querySelectorAll("content");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

What am I missing? What should be changed to always reflect the correct value? (Note: I want to use a references data property to easily change "value" just by setting it.)

Thanks for enlightenment.

My interactive fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/tvjquwmn/

Answer (score 2):

Your data property is not reactive as it refer to a primitive type. It will indeed not be updated after the created step.
If you want it to be reactive, make it computed instead:

```js
Vue.component('edit-element', {
  template: `
  <div>
    <span v-html="direct ? xmlNode.firstChild.nodeValue : value"></span>
    <span style="font-size: 60%; color:grey">({{ keyVal }})</span>
  </div>`,
  props: ["xmlNode", "keyVal", "direct"],
  computed: {
    value() {
        return this.xmlNode.firstChild.nodeValue;
    }
  }
});
```

See working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/56c7utvc/

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer and the working example. I still don't fully understand it. And I want to be able to change the value in a later step. How to do that?

Comment: Your data() function is only run once, when the component is created. It's not re-run in the next render steps, so they will stay static except if they are explicitly updated. On the other hand, computed properties are reactive and will watch for changes on their dependencies.

Comment: This makes sense. And yet I don't get it as I use a unique :key attribute which IMHO shold cause an explicit update. I want to be able to change that value in a later step? What is your suggestion?

Comment: It does not have anything to do with :key. The thing is that `this.xmlNode.firstChild.nodeValue` is a primitive value. So it's not passed as a reference when you assign it to `value` in your data function (only run once), it's copied (not the same entity anymore). Then, the copied value is proxied by vue to be watched. But the original property is not. So, then, `data.value`, while reactive itself, will not react to change on `firstChild.nodeValue`, because your `data.value` is not linked to `firstChild.nodeValue` in any way, they are completely separate.

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot for your explanation. I thought that a new component will be created depending of the :key attribute. I then don't really understand what :key is for.

Comment: `key` is an attribute to identify nodes when using v-for. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: I think, the real issue is elsewhere. I've updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tvjquwmn/1/ and added a console.log in mounted with the id of the element. In the logs you can see that existing elements will be mounted again getting renamed with the new id. I think the problem is, that I change the id of the element which causes a re-rendering (and renaming) and then do an async operation.